# Is my pineapple plant growing another pineapple?

Tags: houseplants, pineapple

I've read that pineapple plants grow only one pineapple, and possibly additional crowns from which more pineapples can grow.

But my plant is growing something that looks like another pineapple (judging by the roundness and bumps), and it isn't coming from another crown.

Have a look under the pineapple fruit in the attached picture...

[image: my pineapple plant]

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pineapple produces what are called "suckers" in the axils of the leaves below the fruiting top, as opposed to "crown" pieces from above the fruit or "slips" from the base. These will produce leaves first and then if left alone they will produce a "ratoon crop" of small pineapples. To judge from the colour of the pineapple on your plant (BTW looks absolutely delicious), the fruit is now at ideal maturity and is signalling to the parent plant it is time to propagate itself. Let the suckers grow a bit and when a decent size pull off and plant to make more pineapples.

Just look up "pineapple suckers" to get lots of references, or visit for example https://www.tropicalpermaculture.com/pineapple-growing.html

Comment: Thanks! I thought suckers are just like slips but growing from the axil instead of between the leaves. That's why I was confused. Or maybe they are the same and I've just never seen it in early stages, since the slips are originally hidden between the leaves. The picture is about a week old, and the pineapple smells amazing and will soon be eaten :)